# Searching an object array to match an input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I am trying to get something to work and I am hitting a brick wall that I am certain is just due to my inexperience.

In the following code, I am trying to take what the user puts in (!activate [card name]) for a trading card game (Bakugan) and have the system find the card from a all lower case, no spaces format. I have a separate cardlist.js file that has the cards set as objects. I've tried so many different ways and I keep getting "____ is not a function" or it just can't find the item in the cardlist file for some reason. I know I have been dancing around it across the hours of trying.

```html
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const cardlist = require('../cardlist.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    //console.log("works");
    //let aUser = `${message.author}`;
    let aCard = message.content.slice(10);
    oCard = Object.filter(function(cardlist){ 
        return cardlist.name === aCard });
    if (aCard === oCard) {
        console.log('Cards match!');
     } else {
         console.log(`Cannot find ${aCard}`)
     }
    }

module.exports.help = {
    name: "activate"
}
```

This is using a command handler. I have many other commands working correctly with it. The code worked up until I was trying to get the aCard and oCard to match. I have also tried searching the card list for the entry that matches what the user puts in as the Card Name. Below is my layout of the cardlist.js

```html
const cardlist = {
    pyrushyperdragonoid: {
        image: 'https://bakugan.wiki/wiki/images/thumb/3/3b/Hyper_Dragonoid_%28Pyrus_Card%29_265_RA_BB.png/250px-Hyper_Dragonoid_%28Pyrus_Card%29_265_RA_BB.png',
        name: 'Pyrus Hyper Dragonoid',
        faction: 'Pyrus',
        energy: 1,
        BPower: '400',
        Type: 'Evo',
        Damage: 6,
        Effect: ':redfist: : +300 :Bicon: and +3:attackicon:'
    },
    dragosfury: {
        name: 'Drago\'s Fury',
        Energy: 2,
        Type: 'Action',
        Effect: '+4:attackicon:. Fury: If you have no cards in hand, +:doublestrike:'
    }
}
```

So, for example: 1) The user puts in the command "!activate pyrushyperdragonoid"
2) I would like the bot to automatically snip off the "!activate" on the input. (Done without error)
3) The bot should then take that entry and search the cardlist.js for it and retrieve all the other parts of that card listing.
4) I haven't done it in this code yet, but I am going to use a RichEmbed to display all the info once retrieved.

I hope all this makes sense! Thank you for any and all help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.filter` does not exist, and even if it did: what is [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)?

Since you have a command handler, your piece of code here could receive from it only the "arguments", i.e. not the whole message but only what comes after the bang command (here `!activate`), this would avoid the barely understandable `.slice(10)`. Anyway.

You don't want to match the human-readable name apparently (`"Pyrus Hyper Dragonoid"`), you want to match the key name (`pyrushyperdragonoid`, better not be dyslexic). You can address it like any object, with brackets for the key:

```
// aCard sounds like an object of the same nature as oCard, but it's just a string
var userInput = message.content.slice(10);
var oCard = cardlist[userInput];
// then you can test
if (oCard) {
  console.log(`You legitimately chose to activate ${oCard.name}!`);
  // here oCard is a sub-object of cardlist, such as { image: '...', name: '...', faction... }
} else {
  console.log(`No mighty beast answered to the name ${userInput}!`);
  // here oCard is undefined
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I certainly had tried something like this before. However, when I type into Discord "!activate pyrushyperdragonoid" it still prints "No mighty beast answered to the name pyrushyperdragonoid". I was getting this a lot when I was trying to figure this out. It is like it doesn't even link to the list... so it has nothing to compare to so it will always print undefined. I currently have the list as .js. Should it be .json instead?

Comment: Just to try it out, I did convert the cardlist.js to cardlist.json, making sure to change it in the require declaration.This time I get "You legitimately chose to activate undefined!". Has to be something small that is causing it to not work...

Comment: Right I didn't look closely at `cardlist.js`, indeed JSON seems more appropriate but JS would have worked, had you simply exported the value of `const cardlist` (you know: `module.exports = ...`). And my bad, my code is totally wrong, I was not well awoken, I'll edit.

Comment: YES! That worked wonders! Thanks so much for your help! Now I'm going to add the Rich Embed to display the info while hoping to not break it!